# URL in Twitter profile

Tags: twitter

When creating a Twitter profile I noticed that all URLs I entered in the profile where changed from:

`http://www.abzurb.com` to `abzurb.com` and it uses a `t.co` link to link to the page.

`https://twitter.com/abzurb`

On most other Twitter profiles it just displays the full URL: `http://www.blabla.com`

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter wraps all URLs, in part of their content - bio, profile, tweets using their in-house URL shortener, primarily for their analytics & for security against malicious URLs.

Now on twitter's webpage as well on their API, twitter provides both the short URL, the the display URL as well as the actual URL

Here's an example from my [twitter profile](http://twitter.com/sathyabhat)

```
 "id": 11594372,
  "id_str": "11594372",
  "name": "Sathya",
  "screen_name": "SathyaBhat",
  "location": "Bangalore, India",
  "description": "Super User & Web Apps Stack Exchange ♦, PLSQL Dev, Mangalorean, Rum, Beer, @Preshit certified lazyass, LOLG Nexus 4, Gaming http://t.co/fZDbzJdc",
  "url": "http://sathyabh.at",
  "entities":  {
    "url":  {
      "urls":  [
         {
          "url": "http://sathyabh.at",
          "expanded_url": null,
          "indices":  [
            0,
            18
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "description":  {
      "urls":  [
         {
          "url": "http://t.co/fZDbzJdc",
          "expanded_url": "http://sbhat.me",
          "display_url": "sbhat.me",
          "indices":  [
            124,
            144
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

You can see that `display_url` is what twitter shows on their websites. Many twitter clients do not handle these well; some show `expanded_url`, others `display_url` while some more just show the shortened t.co URL.

---

While this is the explanation for why it looks different, there's no way to change this - that's how twitter does things.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, but how come some profiles have a display_url of http://www.xyz.com and others don't?

Comment: @Stofke Link me to those profiles?

Comment: "@psdtuts, @DesignerDepot" for example they don't have the t.co in their urls

Comment: @Stofke those are URLs in the profile URL field, not the bio. They are not wrapped in t.co. Look above for same behaviour in my profile

Comment: I notice but how come my account is wrapped in t.co?  I can't explain unless all new accounts are?

www.twitter.com/abzurb